# How to get the AsyncDocumentClient from the CosmosAsyncClient?

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-java-sdk

I use the latest version of Azure Cosmos DB Java SDK v4. I have an instance of `CosmosAsyncClient` and `CosmosAsyncDatabase`. How can I get legal access to the `AsyncDocumentClient`?

I need it for creating an attachment. All samples for attachments starts with an `AsyncDocumentClient`.

I have found `CosmosBridgeInternal` and `BridgeInternal`. But this are internal APIs.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but attachments functionality in Cosmos DB has been deprecated. You should use blob storage to store attachments.

Comment: Blob storage seems a large configuration and cost overhead for a small count of binary data.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that. However considering attachments functionality is deprecated, it may not be a good idea to use that.

Comment: I save the binary data in the object self now as byte array.

Comment: @Horcrux7 can you share the answer on how you did that?

Comment: What you does not understand with saving as byte array? The Item object has an `public byte[]  data`